# How do you fold functions automatically?

Tags: folding

Is there a way to make Vim fold functions based on the syntax of a function declaration?

For example having vim turn a function like this:

```
def foobar(foo,bar):
  if foo > bar:
    print "foo"
  elif foo < bar:
    print "bar"
  elif foo == bar:
    print "foobar"
```

Into this:

```
+----- 7 lines: def foobar(foo,bar): -------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there some set of commands or a function I can put into my .vimrc file use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 13):

Given that your example is in Python, which relies on correct indentation of code blocks it is enough to base folding on that:

```
:set foldmethod=indent
```

For more information on the varieties of folding available see [:help foldmethod](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27foldmethod%27)

Answer (score 8):

Sure:

```
set foldmethod=syntax
```

You can then use `zc` to close a fold, `zo` to open one, or `za` to toggle.

Unfortunately, Vim doesn't include folding information for Python by default, which you appear to be using. You could use [one of many external resources](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2462), however.

Comment: In order for this to work the syntax file you are using should make use of `syn-fold`. in my installation of vim74, only about 10% of the syntax files use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my vimrc command to automatically fold a function pressing F4 when my cursor is placed on the function definition:

```
" fold whole function
nmap <silent> <F4> /{<CR>zfa}
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Note that you may want to consider using `nnoremap`. Also your mapping is specific to C-like/braces languages, while the OP specifically mentions other styles. Mentioning this caveat would probably improve the answer, as well as suggest possible ways to generalize. You can always [edit] to update and improve the answer.